# How can I dynamically specify the 'key' name on Firebase Database update() method?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an Angular 4 application using TypeScript, and I would like to add some data into the Firebase database using the `update()` method while dynamically specifying the 'key' name from the `userId` property:

```
this.products = this.afdb.list('/products/');

this.products.update(this.productId, {
    this.userId : this.myRating
})
```

The problem here is that `this.userId` cannot be added as the 'key' name. Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe: `this.products.update(this.productId, (o={}, o[this.userId] = this.myRating, o))`. However, it would be visible better to create a function that takes in the `this` arg and returns your object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use a different object notation...

```
{
    this.userId : this.myRating
}
```

does not work.

Try this:

```
var obj = {};
obj[this.userId] = this.myRating;
this.products.update(this.productId, obj);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The result that I would like to achieve is a bit different. I would like to have the 'userId' in place of the 'rating', so the result would be something like this: ... '001: 5' .... where '001' is the userId and '5' is the rating.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late but provides a way to save a 'dynamically' specified attribute name in firestore:

```
const docRef = admin.firestore().collection("products").doc("productID");
const myObj: {[key: string]: admin.firestore.FieldValue} = {};
obj[this.userId] = this.myRating;

docRef.set(myObj, {merge: true});
```

[How to change the value of a field (obtained dynamically) in firestore document from cloud functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73279513/how-to-change-the-value-of-a-field-obtained-dynamically-in-firestore-document#73279513)