# How to change the value of a field (obtained dynamically) in firestore document from cloud functions?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My question is really simple. How can I update a field in a firestore document if the name of the field is only known dynamically in a variable?

```
const myCounterName = "exampleName";
const docRef = admin.firestore().collection("metadata").doc("myDoc");
docRef.set({myCounterName : admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)}, {merge: true});
```

The problem is that firestore is going to consider that the name of the field I want to change is "myCounterName" and not "exampleName".

Answer (score 2):

You can do as follows, using the [square brackets notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors):

```
const myCounterName = "exampleName";

const payloadObj = {};
payloadObj[myCounterName] = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);

const docRef = admin.firestore().collection("metadata").doc("myDoc");
docRef.set(payloadObj, {merge: true});
```

Comment: Works like a charm. In typescript the following type must be specified for it to compile :  `const payloadObj : { [key: string]: admin.firestore.FieldValue } = {};`